# Problems to get path from other activity / layout

Tags: java, android

first of all. I´m still a rookie in android...
I have two activites / layouts

1. activity_main (Class Main.java) gives the user the possibility to pick a picture from the gallery
2. activity_upload (Class Upload.java) should display the selected picture. (In the future, there will be an upload to a server)

My problem is: The view in activity_upload don´t show the preview of the selected picture. 
I have a variable "picturepath". This variable i try to make available in the activity_upload with "bundle..."

Could anybody help me? Thank you

I´ve now tried this, but it also doesn´t work.

Main.java

```
 if (requestCode == RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && null != data) {
    Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
    String[] filePathColumn = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };

    Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(selectedImage,
            filePathColumn, null, null, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    int columnIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(filePathColumn[0]);
    String picturePath = cursor.getString(columnIndex);
    cursor.close();
    Intent in = new Intent(Main.this, Upload.class);
    in.putExtra("Path", picturePath);
    startActivity(in);
}
```

Upload.java

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        String picturePath = getIntent().getStringExtra("Path");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imgView);
        imageView.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeFile(picturePath));        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you nowhere call explicit your Upload class via Intent so then your Upload class won't know about path to picture.

You need to create Intent for switching to Upload Activity and you need to pack some data with it. It can achieve with `putExtra()` method. Then you can get data in class via

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("key");
```

**Pseudocode:**

```
Intent i = new Intent(Main.this, Upload.class);
i.putExtra("picPath", "<someValue>");
startActivity(i);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple problems that I see. First, I don't see how you expect to get

```
 String picturePath = ptarget.getString("Bilderpfad");
```

for this to happen you would have to do something like

```
intent.putExtra("Bilderpfad", value)";
```

when you send the `Intent` to this `Activity`. Secondly, you call `onActivityResult()` but this would only be called when you start an `Intent` from this class with `startActivityForResult()` and then call `setResult()` from the called class, which I don't see you doing. Unless I missed something, you need to go through the [INtent Docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

I think you are close but I believe that you are missing some key fundamentals on how `Activities` and `Intents` work

Comment: @user2026823 what is the exact problem you are having? The variable is `null`, `onActivityResult` doesn't get called, something else?